# Regex identical strings on same line matching

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a specific string pattern using java regex.

I want to find pattern like

```
{some stuff|other stuff}
```

I am using the following  pattern:

```
"(\\{#" + key + ")(\\|.*)[^\\}]"
```

Problem is that when I have something like:

```
text...     {some stuff|other stuff}  {some stuff|other stuff}  more text
```

I am matching `{some stuff|other stuff}  {some stuff|other stuff}` and not 2 occurrences of {some stuff|other stuff}.

I think this is somehow related to the regex backtracking but I have no idea on how to get around it.

Any ideas?

My Java code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{#" + key + ")(\\|.*)[^\\}]");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);

while (m.find()) {
    logger.info(m.group(0));
    //logger.warn("Parameter " + key + " is not found");
    //  throw new Exception("Parameter " + key + " is not found");
}
```

Comment: what about a second Pattern to have the match splitted?

Comment: What is `key`?? What  exact output do you need (say, for `{some stuff|other stuff}`)? Please show the real-life example.

Comment: This question is unclear.  Please provide some concrete examples of strings you'd like to match and the expected match groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.matches("({"+key.replace('.',"\\.").replace('|',"\\|")+"|(.*)})+")`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `(\\{#" + key + ")(\\|)(.+?})`  as a pattern solved my problem. I did not take into consideration that my search had greedy behavior.

Thank you for your answers they helped me solve my problem.

Comment: It won't work if your `key` is say, `#my*key`. Or, if the part after `|` contains a linebreak.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `*`-quantified negated character class `[^}]*` and do not forget to `Pattern.quote` the variable string you pass to the pattern to be used as a sequence of literal chars.

The pattern should look like

```
\{(#\Qmy.key\E)\|([^}]*)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DdMyvo/1).

*Details*:

- `\{` - a literal `{`
- `(#\Qmy.key\E)` - Group 1 capturing a literal `my.key`
- `\|` - a literal `|`
- `([^}]*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than `}`
- `}`  - a literal `}`

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/G7ka0A):

```
String key = "my.key";
String s = "text...     {#my.key|other_stuff}  {#my.key|new\nstuff}  more\ntext";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(#" + Pattern.quote(key) + ")\\|([^}]*)}");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("--- Match found ---");
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```